# Getting data collection timeout when trying to build in local machine

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hope you're doing okay. So I've developed my first NextJS app and I seem to come to a deadend when trying to build on localhost.

The app is using SSG and ISR to get data from the database. The database consists of 3 tables with 1 table having more than 70k records, another with 15k and the last one with 400 records.

In the homepage of the app, data is being fetched with getStaticProps from '70k records table' and returning around 2000 records.

For categories, which is a nested dynamic route ( /example.com/categories/[slug]/[page] ), data is being fetched in "slug" as well as "page" with getStaticPaths and getStaticProps.

The same way it does in authors page.

Now the issue is whenever I run npm run build, it times out with the following error:

```
Error: Collecting page data for /authors/[slug] is still timing out after 2 attempts. See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-data-collection-timeout
```

I tried adding a longer timeout in next.config.js "staticPageGenerationTimeout" with time more than 1000s, it still times out.

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1500
}
```

After using 1500 seconds as timeout, the build still ends with an error within 2-3 minutes. Seems like `staticPageGenerationTimeout` is not working.

I also tried building the app in my VPS thinking a VPS is more powerful and will be able to do it fast but the process ends with this:

```
info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...Killed
```

What could be going wrong here? How can I fix it? Please note that I have some "missing dependency in useEffect" warnings while building. I suppose that is not an issue.

UPDATE

This is how category [slug] and category [page] route looks like. Same with author [slug] and author [page]:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

    await dbConnect();

    const aggregateObj = [ 
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'categories', 
                'localField': 'categories.category', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'categories'
            }
        }, 
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'posts', 
                'localField': 'post', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'post'
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'authors', 
                'localField': 'author', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'author'
            }
        }
    ]

    const result = await PostModel
        .aggregate( aggregateObj )
        .exec(); 

    const posts = result.map(( doc ) => {
        const item = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( doc ) );
        return item;
    });

    const pageSize   = 6;
    const totalPages = Math.round( posts.length / pageSize );

    const pageNumbers = [];
    for ( let i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++ ) {
        pageNumbers.push( i );
    }

    const paths = pageNumbers.map( ( item ) => ( {
        params: {
            slug: posts[ 0 ].categories[ 0 ].categorySlug,
            page: String( item )
        }
    } ) );

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking'
    };

}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {

    await dbConnect();

    const aggregateObj = [ 
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'categories', 
                'localField': 'categories.category', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'categories'
            }
        }, 
        {
            '$match': {
                "categories.categorySlug": params.slug
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'posts', 
                'localField': 'post', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'post'
            }
        },
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': 'authors', 
                'localField': 'author', 
                'foreignField': '_id', 
                'as': 'author'
            }
        }
    ]

    const result = await PostModel
        .aggregate( aggregateObj )
        .exec(); 

    const posts = result.map(( doc ) => {
        const item = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( doc ) );
        return item;
    });

    const perPage     = 6;
    const totalPages  = Math.round( posts.length / perPage );
    const currentPage = Number( params.page );


    const getPaginatedData = () => {
        const startIndex = currentPage * perPage - perPage;
        const endIndex   = startIndex + perPage;
        return posts.slice( startIndex, endIndex );
    };
   
    if ( posts.length === 0 || currentPage > totalPages ) {
        return { 
          notFound: true
        }
    }

    return {
        props: { 
            topicName: posts[ 0 ].categories[ 0 ].category,
            topicSlug: params.slug,
            totalPages, 
            currentPage,
            posts: getPaginatedData()
        },
    }

}
```

Comment: It'll be more helpful if you include your code. It seems some Promises are not properly handled in your `getStaticPaths` or `getServeSideProps.`

Comment: @GeniusHawlah Bro, I updated the OP. Please check it. Also please note that it works in development mode. It just doesn't work when I try to build.

Comment: I have same problem. Is there any solution? I can build in dev mode but it's don't work on vercel

Comment: Any solution has been found ?

Answer (score 0):

**staticPageGenerationTimeout** was introduced in NextJS 12, which is a fairly recent release. Please ensure your environment isn't NextJS < 12.